# How to convert hmtl5 to apk?

Tags: html, apk

I can only publish my project in html5 (not a coder) I have my application design in html5 on my laptop. I need a way to convert this to apk for uploading to play store. Is there a way for me to do that?

I have created the project on adobe captivate. I have published it in html5. I tried to use cordova and ionics. But with no coding background, I did not manage to do that.

Comment: Hire someone who has `coding background, who will manage to do that`

Answer (score 1):

Read about [cordova](https://www.joshmorony.com/the-step-by-step-guide-to-publishing-a-html5-mobile-application-on-app-stores/)

or you can find other tutorials on google.
Cordova can help you to convert `HTML5` web app to `Android App`

or we have one more [phonegap](https://phonegap.com/)

Comment: Good answer. That's something hard to find though!

Comment: Nobody use it, obviously @BlackMamba

Comment: Thank you for your comments :)) I managed to generate apk by watching tutorials. I could also zipalign, and generate the key. Playstore says 32bit apks are not allowed anymore. Do you know how I can modify my apk to 64 bit?